# Тень блока при наложении блоков

Tags: html, css

http://ggrgb.com/forstackoverflow/ 
Внизу страницы есть блок с изображениями логотипов социальных сетей. Установлено свойство при `:hover` на этом блоке добавлять `box-shadow`. Оно работает, но из за наложения блоков, у первого и второго блока видно только верхнюю и левую тень, у третьего +правую. Реально ли убрать эффект наложения, и отображать тень на всех гранях? Пытался применить 
`z-index`, не помогло.

Код(только код, результат не корректный): https://jsfiddle.net/Shosty/ffue02gh/2/ - источник

```css
.socialseti {
    margin-top: 295px;
    width: 1170px;
    background-color: black;
}
.socialseti a{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.socialseti > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 390px;
    height: 150px;
    border: none;
}
.socialseti > div:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    z-index: 3;
}
.socialseti div:nth-child(1){
    background-color: #3b5997;
    padding-top: 44px;
        height: 106px;
}
.socialseti div:nth-child(2){
    background-color:  #3fccfd;
    padding-top: 49px;
    height: 101px;
}
.socialseti div:nth-child(3){
    background-color:  #cb2027;
    padding-top: 43px;
    height: 107px;
```

```html
<div class="socialseti">
    <div class="fb">
        <a href = "#"><img src="images/f%20icon.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="tw">
        <a href = "#"><img src="images/tw%20icon.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pin">
        <a href = "#"><img src="images/pin%20icon.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Код нужно перенести в вопрос

Comment: добавьте `position: relative` ко всем `div` соц. сетей

Comment: @ScreamingVoices +

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте свойство:

```
.socialseti > div:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}
```

> Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.socialseti {
    margin-top: 295px;
    width: 1170px;
    background-color: black;
}
.socialseti a{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.socialseti > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 390px;
    height: 150px;
    border: none;
}
.socialseti > div:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    z-index: 3;
}
.socialseti div:nth-child(1){
    background-color: #3b5997;
    padding-top: 44px;
        height: 106px;
}
.socialseti div:nth-child(2){
    background-color:  #3fccfd;
    padding-top: 49px;
    height: 101px;
}
.socialseti div:nth-child(3){
    background-color:  #cb2027;
    padding-top: 43px;
    height: 107px;
}
.socialseti > div:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="socialseti">
    <div class="fb">
        <a href = "#"><img src="images/f%20icon.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="tw">
        <a href = "#"><img src="images/tw%20icon.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pin">
        <a href = "#"><img src="images/pin%20icon.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: и тень  находится под элементов предыдущего

Comment: @МаксимЛенский  где?

Comment: там же на сайте и даже у вас на скрине - смотрите сами

Comment: видите - вы наводите на твиттер а тень под правым

Comment: @МаксимЛенский не понимаю. https://ibb.co/mWii5w

Comment: наверно на скрине так видно - прошу прощения

Comment: @МаксимЛенский да, цвет тени не очень хорошо видно